# Почему капча с сайта roblox-а передается пустой на 2captcha?

Tags: python, requests, captcha, roblox

*Капча - arcose labs fun captcha*

*сайт - roblox.com*

*Сервис - 2captcha*

Пытаюсь отправить капчу на решение в 2captcha. Она приходит туда в виде пустого белого листа. нет ни кнопок ни каких-либо других данные о капче. Проверял руками через инструмент sandbox в 2captcha. Соответственно воркеры 2captcha наблюдают идентичную картину. Поэтому вместо решенной капчи мне приходит - **ERROR_CAPTCHA_UNSOLVABLE.**

Пробовал брать public_key капчи с сайта https://octocaptcha.com/ (пример) и мой скрипт отлично отрабатывает. Капча передается сервису.
В sandbox ее видно.

**Мой код:**

```
import json
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Value

captcha_api_key = "Ключ"
main_page = "https://www.roblox.com/"
login_url = "https://auth.roblox.com/v1/login"
login_data = {"ctype": "Username", "cvalue": "Никнейм", "password": "Пароль"}
captcha_metadata_url = "https://apis.rbxcdn.com/captcha/v1/metadata"
surl = "https%3A%2F%2Froblox-api.arkoselabs.com"

s = requests.Session()
resp1 = s.get(main_page)
root = BeautifulSoup(resp1.text, "html.parser")

meta_element = root.find('meta', attrs={'data-token': True})

if meta_element:
    data_token_value = meta_element['data-token']
    print('Значение атрибута data-token:', data_token_value)
else:
    print('Элемент <meta> с атрибутом data-token не найден.')

s.headers["X-CSRF-TOKEN"] = data_token_value


resp = s.post(login_url, login_data)
if resp.text == '{"errors":[{"code":0,"message":"Challenge is required to authorize the request"}]}':
    captcha_metadata = s.get(captcha_metadata_url)
    captcha_metadata = json.loads(captcha_metadata.text)
    public_key = captcha_metadata.get("funCaptchaPublicKeys").get("ACTION_TYPE_WEB_LOGIN")
    print(public_key)
    captcha_post = s.post(f"http://2captcha.com/in.php?key={captcha_api_key}&method=funcaptcha&publickey={public_key}&surl={surl}&pageurl=https://auth.roblox.com/v1/login")
    captcha_id = captcha_post.text[3:]
    while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        captcha_result = s.get(f"http://2captcha.com/res.php?key={captcha_api_key}&action=get&id={captcha_id}")
        if captcha_result.text != "CAPCHA_NOT_READY":
            if captcha_result.text == "ERROR_CAPTCHA_UNSOLVABLE":
                print("Нерешаемая капча")
                break
            else:
                print(captcha_result.text)
                break
```

**Может пригодится**

Блок с капчей появляется **после** Попытки логина. Изначально ее **нет**.
Public_key я получаю с metadata, ссылку на которую достал изучая network. - там содержится список всех публичных ключей. Выглядит примерно так:

```
{
    "funCaptchaPublicKeys": {
        "ACTION_TYPE_ASSET_COMMENT": "63E4117F-E727-42B4-6DAA-C8448E9B137F",
        "ACTION_TYPE_CLOTHING_ASSET_UPLOAD": "63E4117F-E727-42B4-6DAA-C8448E9B137F",
        "ACTION_TYPE_FOLLOW_USER": "63E4117F-E727-42B4-6DAA-C8448E9B137F",
        "ACTION_TYPE_GENERIC_CHALLENGE": "CC30DB96-0C88-4DEB-86E5-6601927ACBB4",
        "ACTION_TYPE_GROUP_JOIN": "63E4117F-E727-42B4-6DAA-C8448E9B137F",
        "ACTION_TYPE_GROUP_WALL_POST": "63E4117F-E727-42B4-6DAA-C8448E9B137F",
        "ACTION_TYPE_MARKETPLACE": "63E4117F-E727-42B4-6DAA-C8448E9B137F",
        "ACTION_TYPE_SUPPORT_REQUEST": "63E4117F-E727-42B4-6DAA-C8448E9B137F",
        "ACTION_TYPE_WEB_GAMECARD_REDEMPTION": "1B154715-ACB4-2706-19ED-0DC7E3F7D855",
        "ACTION_TYPE_WEB_LOGIN": "476068BF-9607-4799-B53D-966BE98E2B81",
        "ACTION_TYPE_WEB_RESET_PASSWORD": "476068BF-9607-4799-B53D-966BE98E2B81",
        "ACTION_TYPE_WEB_SIGNUP": "A2A14B1D-1AF3-C791-9BBC-EE33CC7A0A6F"
    },
    "captchaVersion": "",
    "disableCaptchaVersionExperiment": false
}
```

Ключ (в нашем случае ACTION_TYPE_WEB_LOGIN) совпадает с тем что находится на странице в html коде после появления блока с капчей.

В ответе объясните почему передается "пустая" капча и как это исправить. Отредактируйте код под "правильный".

**Жду ответов, спасибо.**

Comment: изложите, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса (нажав [edit]), какого рода «ответов» вы ожидаете.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Поправил, думаю ясно описал на этот раз. Спасибо